# RestExplorer in Workbench Get Error?

Tags: apex, rest-api, workbench, restresource

I would like to test a Get endpoint in Workbench via the rest Explorer. However I'm getting a services not found error when executing.  Any suggestions on what I need to change? Below is the endpoint I'm entering 
/services/data/v40.0/FEApplicationDataById/V1

Here is my Rest Class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/FEApplicationDataById/V1')
global class FEApplicationDataById {
@HTTPGet
global static JSONData getFEApplicationData () {
    RestRequest req =  RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    res.addHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    req.headers.get('pidm');
    req.headers.get('idStringList');
    String pidm  = req.params.get('pidm');
    String idStringList = req.params.get('idStringList');
    System.debug('PIDM='+pidm);
    //calls the populateFEAppDataById method to do json population.       
    JSONData feData = populateFEAppDataById(pidm, idStringList);

    return feData;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use following:

```
https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/FEApplicationDataById/V1
```

Workbench conveniently takes care of the ...yourInstance.salesforce.com... part so in the Rest Explorer input box you just need to change `/services/data/`... to `/services/apexrest/`... when trying to access your Custom Apex REST resources.

For more information, refer [Apex Web Services](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_webservices)